# How to remove `constexpr` from type of variable

Tags: c++, constexpr, decltype

`Constexpr` seems to be part of a variable's type (received via `decltype(...)`), as the following assertion fails:

```
constexpr int variable {};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, std::remove_cvref<std::decay<decltype(variable)>>>);
```

Is there a helper structure in the standard library which I can use on the second argument of `is_same_v` in order to make the assertion `true`?
I currently use the following workaround which I would like to replace with a proper solution:

```
template <typename T> T func();
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(func<decltype(variable)>())>);
```

The code is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/shx7f3); I use this for restricting a non-type template parameter's auto-deduced type.

Comment: You need `std::remove_cvref_t`, and the type of `constexpr int` is `const int`. Since you use remove_cv (remove const volatile), they are the same.

Comment: Ouh thanks! You're right, that's what I thought in the beginning but I was put off by the fact that the assertion failed due to my error. When I use `remove_cvref_t<...>` the assertion works just fine.

Comment: You have the same issue with `std::decay`. Had you used `std::decay_t` it would have worked too.

Comment: `decay_t` and `remove_cvref_t` seem an overkill. decay_t alone would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`constexpr` only changes the variable's type to `const`, hence for instance `std::remove_cvref_t<...>` can be used to "fix" the assertion. Therefore, the  following static assertions both compile:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int const, decltype(variable)>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, std::remove_cv_t<decltype(variable)>>);
```

Due to a typo, the argument in the question's assertion falsely compares the type of the struct `remove_cvref` with `int`, as the suffix `_t` (aliasing to `remove_cvref<...>::type`) is missing. This type  is not the same as `int` which causes the static_assertion to fail.